# How to access a field in the superclass from a subclass?

Tags: java

I have the two classes here, Minesweeper is a child of Battleship

```
public class Battleship 
{
 private Part part[];

 public boolean hit(int row, int column)

{
    Part newpart = new Part(row,column);

    for(int i=0; i<part.length;i++)
    {
        if (part[i].equals(newpart))
        {
            part[i].setDestroyed(true);
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false; 
}
```

And for the Minesweeper Class I have

```
public class Minesweeper extends Battleship 
{
   public Minesweeper()
   {
       super(2);
   }

   @Override
   public boolean hit(int row, int column)
   {
       return true;
   }
```

}

How Can I access the array *part* without using a getter or making it public. As it says in the assignment that we can't access the array part from outside that class.

Thanks so much for any help

Comment: It's `private`. You are not supposed to be able to access it outside of the class (that's the whole purpose of `private`). Make it `protected` if you wish to do so. But why do you want to access it directly instead of using a getter?

Comment: I'm curious why `Minesweeper` would override `hit` in the first place, but I suppose it isn't really important to the underlying question... (If a Minesweeper takes two hits per segment or something like that, it still doesn't necessarily need access to `part`.)

Comment: There is probably a reason why the assignment was done the way it is. They probably don't want you to come up with a modification of the base class but instead use all the methods the base class exposes to you to solve the problem in a clever way. But that's just a guess.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I need to change it so that the chance of hitting the Minesweeper would be 50%

Comment: @J.Marsomn: `@Override public boolean hit(int row, int column) { if (new Random().nextInt(100) < 50) { return false; } return super.hit(row, column); }` :-) But again, not really germane to your underlying question... Or, looking at GhostCat's answer, is it? Anyway, have fun with your game!

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to change the access modifier for that field from *private* to *protected* for example. *public* would work as well.

But please keep in mind: doing so should be the *exception*!

Meaning: good OO design is much more about *behavior* (aka *methods*) than about fields! In other words: one should have really good reasons to expose fields to child classes. Typically, you work the other way round, like:

```
abstract class Base {
  abstract int getFoo();
  final void bar() {
    foo = getFoo(); 
  ...
```

and then classes extending Base simply @Override that method `getFoo()`.

This approach allows you to *fix* certain behavior on the Base class; while preventing subclasses from changing that behavior; but allowing them to provide those details that are "sub class" specific in the end.

Comment: Please can you tell me if there is another way to do it other than using the access modified protected. As I email my lecturer and he said that we are not allowed to do that !

Comment: @J.Marsomn If you're not allowed to change access modifier from private, using a getter/setter is the only way to access it. What about putting all logic in the superclass and calling it from the child?

Comment: @SporreKing Thanks for the reply, I got what you mean. I want to add to the hit method in the superclass (Battleship class) that if ( Minesweeper instanceof Battleship) then do  .... But I can't change the parameters how can I check if the hit is for the subclass or the superclass ? I hope my question is clear. Thanks so much

Comment: @J.Marsomn What do you mean by "if the hit is for the subclass or superclass"? You are still calling the same object, you are just accessing different functions within it.

Comment: @SporreKing So how to add extra functionality to hit when it is for the subclass from the superclass ? Thanks

Comment: @J.Marsomn don't do that. Instead, add functions for each algorithm you want to perform on the array. Add a set(Part p, int i) function to the superclass etc.